# Extract class to a diffrent file keyboard binding / command in VSCode

Tags: python, file, class, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I want to be able to extract an entire class from a python file that contains many classes to its own separate file in the same directory, while the import and references to said class will auto-change after the refactor. Is that possible in VSCode? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can copy all the imports first. The linter will prompt which module is imported but unused.